# Store a PIN of user in an array of PINS in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need some help with my project. 
I have a voting form, where any wordpress registered users can vote once then their PIN (an unique number are stored in an array of PINS) so the button "vote" will be disabled. 
I don't know how to store the pin in an array, and then putting conditions

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
$id = $row[0];
$title = $row[1];
$pollid = $row[2];
$pin = $row[4]

$pin = $current_user->user_pin; (stores the wordpress current user's PIN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get you actually,As I hope I am understand correctly.

**Case 1: as you suggested**

```
 $pin = $current_user->user_pin;
```

You can push an element after vote to dummy array.

```
$pinarr=array();
$pinarr.push($pin);
```

**Case 2: Instead of array please use a flag in database**

I think vote is very sensitive data.

- So that you add one more column in `wp_user` table lets consider as
  `voter_flag`
- set default value 0
- Update flag after vote
- while render page again check if user is `voter_flag` is 0 then active button.